# Quick code for page navigation

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I have Link images and Link page adresses on a table

example of columns 
Linkimage
http://www.site.com/andy.jpg
 
http://www.site.com/bruce.jpg
http://www.site.com/caely.jpg
http://www.site.com/dana.jpg

LinkPage
http://www.site.com/andy.php 
http://www.site.com/bruce.php
http://www.site.com/caely.php
http://www.site.com/dana.php

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT Nname, Linkimg, Linkpage, 
");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['N'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Linkpage']}\"><img src=\"{$row['Linkimge']}\">" . "</td>";
```

I need a small code to display it as a next item on the name address arrow navigation
like the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxudu.jpg

page andy

<-- picture(Andy)  picture(Bruce)  --->

page Bruce

<-- picture(Andy)  picture(Caely)  --->

Page Caely

<-- picture(Bruce)  picture(Dana)  --->

is this complicated? I have looked for site navigation scripts but I don't think they are what I need

Comment: ,do u need images followed by name and address? as shown in the link?

Comment: Just the image with the link attached to the image

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment use `<a href`for image and link it the page you need...

`<a href="<img src=<?php echo $row['image'];?>" ><?php echo $row["link"];?></a>`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, You are looking for a structure like this

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><<</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img alt="sample1"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img alt="sample2"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">>></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul > li {
    margin-left: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8E6n9/)

Comment: i was looking for an autoincrement

Comment: @user3375733 What do you mean by auto-increment?

Answer (score 0):

I would like an autoincrement on this code

```
<table width="" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php
include("databaseopen.php");
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT Linkimage, Linkpage
FROM NAMES LIMIT 0,1
");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #6666CC;'>";
echo "<td align='center' width=''>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Linkpage']}\"><img src=\"leftarrow.gif\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width=''>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Linkpage']}\"><img src=\"{$row['Linkimage']}\">" . "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?></td>
    <td><?php
include("databaseopen.php");
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT Limg, Lpage
FROM ACT LIMIT 73,1
");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #6666CC;'>";
echo "<td align='center' width=''>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Linkpage']}\"><img src=\"{$row['Linkimage']}\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width=''>" . "<a href=\"{$row['Linkpage']}\"><img src=\"rightarrow.gif\">" . "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```